# python : get the stdout of a docker process launched with subprocess.popen --progress not available anymore

Tags: python, subprocess

Im using popen to launch a docker-compose process.

```
 print(subprocess.Popen('docker-compose -f docker-compose_dev.yml up', shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
```

I get the output :

```
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
b''
Creating network "wagtail-react-blog_spa_network" with the default driver
Creating wagtail-react-blog_backend_1 ... done
Creating wagtail-react-blog_frontend_1 ... done
Creating wagtail-react-blog_nginx_1    ... done
```

But i dont get the outputs of the command run in the docker container which usually appear when i run this command in the terminal. Do you know how i can do to retrieve them? In another script I use a subprocess.check_call to open a sh script and everything is printed, but i would like to avoid to write a sh script.
Thanks

EDIT: it used to work with --progress flag but i dont see it anymore in the docs and i dont have any output. I tried with stdout.read and stderr.read but it's the same

Comment: Docker does weird things to output the logging commands to the terminal, try capturing stderr too, and/or playing with the `--progress` option

Comment: thanks tripleee, you're a great provider of solutions to my posts! :) .